# iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): RULE_APPEND failed (Invalid argument): rule in chain OUTPUT

Tags: iptables

on debian 10 trying to apply following iptable rules:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100


iptables -t mangle -N V2RAY
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY -d 192.168.0.0/16 -p tcp -j RETURN 
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY -d 192.168.0.0/16 -p udp ! --dport 53 -j RETURN 
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY -p udp -j TPROXY --on-port 12345 --tproxy-mark 1 
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port 12345 --tproxy-mark 1 
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j V2RAY 


iptables -t mangle -N V2RAY_MASK
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY_MASK -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY_MASK -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY_MASK -d 192.168.0.0/16 -p tcp -j RETURN 
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY_MASK -d 192.168.0.0/16 -p udp ! --dport 53 -j RETURN 
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY_MASK -j RETURN -m mark --mark 0xff   
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY_MASK -p udp -j MARK --set-mark 1  
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY_MASK -p tcp -j MARK --set-mark 1   
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j V2RAY_MASK
```

but error at last:

```
 iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables):  RULE_APPEND failed (Invalid argument): rule in chain OUTPUT
```

Comment: Simply copy/pasting your rules works here with package iptables 1.8.2-4  displaying `iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables)`. But running kernel 5.4.x. You could double-check if using buster-backports (linux-image-5.4.0-0.bpo.2-amd64) changes your behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue after upgrading Debian 9 -> 10. The problem was old kernel (4.9), and was resolved by upgrading kernel to 4.19 (which is standard for Debian 10).

Answer (score 0):

With the last rule you want to join the `OUTPUT` chain with `V2RAY_MASK` chain. I think `-t mangle` is wrong here.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j V2RAY_MASK
```

Comment: I tried your way and also get error:  iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): Chain 'V2RAY_MASK' does not exist

Comment: Can you add more details such as platform etc?

Comment: Did you paste some strings from Windows? Can you ensure that every `-` is actually `-`? For your reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hyphens_and_dashes

Comment: double checked they are linux -